# A combinatorics question: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac1{2^{2n}} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom nk \binom ni = \frac12$

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Am trying to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{i} =0.5.$

I think that the above result is true but am not sure how to prove this. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The general term is the probability that if one picks a pair of subsets from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, the second has smaller size than the first, so you just need to show that the probability that the two sets have the same size tends to zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can rewrite the sum as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{i}
&=\sum_{0\leq i<k\leq n}\binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{i}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\substack{0\leq i,k\leq n\\i\neq k}}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{i}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{0\leq i\leq n}\binom{n}{i}\right)^2-
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{0\leq i\leq n}\binom{n}{i}^2\\
&=2^{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2}\binom{2n}{n}.
\end{align*}
It is well-known that
$$\binom{2n}{n}\sim\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}},$$
hence
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{i}=\left(\frac{1}{2}-o(1)\right)2^{2n}.$$
The proof is complete.